# mysql: Inserting multiple 'insert into' requests

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use 2 separate `insert into` statements to create 1 row. Since the row uses data from another table (ingredients) AND uses data from a submitted post (the meals name), I am trying to combine the two, so I can create 1 new row with extra data in it.

The problem i'm running into is mysql syntax errors. Is there a way I can use the post data AND the data from my ingredients table to make a new row?

It seems like you can only have `insert into .. select` OR `insert into .. values`, but you can't have both!

```
// Added Ingredients to a Meal
if (isset($_POST['add_ingredient'])){
    $meal = (string)$_POST['meal_names'];
    $ingr = (string)$_POST['ingredients_list'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (quanity, package, cost, store, item)
        SELECT quanity, package, cost, store, item
        FROM ingredients;
        INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (meal)
        VALUES ('$meal')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully.";
    }   
    else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop what you're doing and read up on Sql Injection and PDO.

Comment: Exactly what @Madbreaks said, this code could be easily broken and ruin your database or be used to simply dump the whole thing.